# Rounding up to decimal pgfmath

Tags: calculations, pgfmath, floating-point

I need to define a Roundup function that is "*defined as the smallest number, specified to one decimal place, that is equal to or higher than its input.*" For example, Round up (4.02) is 4.1; and Round up (4.00) is 4.0.

So far I've come up with this MWE, which **nearly** does the job :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\newcommand{\roundup}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{(ceil(#1*10)/10}%
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[precision=1,fixed]{\pgfmathresult}{\roundednumber}
    \roundednumber%
}%


\begin{document}

roundup(4.02) = \roundup{4.02} \qquad (should be 4.1)

roundup(4.0) = \roundup{4.0} \qquad (should be 4.0)

roundup(-0.27) = \roundup{-0.27} \qquad (should be -0.2)

\textbf{Problem : }

roundup(-0.2) = \roundup{-0.2}\qquad (should be -0.2)

\textbf{Reason}

\pgfmathparse{ceil(-2)}\pgfmathresult \qquad(this is OK)

\pgfmathparse{ceil(-0.2*10)}\pgfmathresult \qquad(\textbf{this is KO})

\end{document}
```

However, sometimes it poses problem.

[image: MWE output]

In the end, it boils down to the ceil function, and how pgfmath handles decimal numbers.

How can I right this behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expl3` and its floating point module.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\roundup}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { ceil(#1,1) }
  \fp_compare:nT { ceil(#1,1)=ceil(#1,0) } {.0}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

roundup(4.02) = \roundup{4.02} \qquad (should be 4.1)

roundup(4.0) = \roundup{4.0} \qquad (should be 4.0)

roundup(3.91) = \roundup{3.91} \qquad (should be 4.0)

roundup(-0.27) = \roundup{-0.27} \qquad (should be -0.2)

roundup(-0.2) = \roundup{-0.2}\qquad (should be -0.2)

\end{document}
```

The `\fp_compare:nT` bit is for adding a trailing `.0` which `\fp_eval:n` wouldn't.

[image]

Explanation: `ceil(<expression>,<digits>)` evaluates the ceiling with `<digits>` decimal places; `ceil(<expression>,0)` is equivalent to `ceil(<expression>)`.

Comment: Thanks :) Any luck on getting this solved with `pgfmath` ?

Comment: @3isenHeim This `\roundup` command is fully expandable, so you can use it anywhere